# .htaccess RewriteRule in subdirectory with PHP GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two problems here pertaining to the `.htaccess` and PHP GET variables.

Basically, I'm working on an anime site, and I want to be able to load up `site.com/anime/AnimeName`

Right now, I have it as `site.com/anime/index.php?watch=AnimeName`

I was able to do this for my users profiles:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

I tried similar approaches with the `.htaccess` in the `/anime/` subdirectory, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My second issue (isn't as big deal as the main issue), is I'd like to know how I can set TWO variables for .htaccess files.

Ex: I have episodes for `site.com/anime/?watch=AnimeName&ep=Ep#`

Basically, I want to know how I can get it to be like this: 
`site.com/anime/AnimeName/1` for episode one, `site.com/anime/AnimeName/2` for episode two, and so on.

---

**UPDATE:** I did this in my main `.htaccess` file and it works for both usernames and anime.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ /anime.php?watch=$1
```

Now, how can I make it to where I can do this: 
`site.com/a/AnimeName/1` for Episode 1?

I've tried this but it didn't work: 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a/&ep=$1
Either way, 
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: How does the url for profiles look? Where is you htaccess file?

Comment: User URLs are like this: /u/Username

Comment: .htaccess is saved in root directory. I managed to get /a/ to work for anime.php and /u/ work for profile.php along with the first GET variable (/a/AnimeName and /u/Username) but I want ANOTHER GET variable to be like this: /a/AnimeName/ep# and /u/Username/post#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite conditions **only** get applied to the *immediately following* rule. So you need to duplicate the conditions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ /anime.php?watch=$1 [L]
```

However, if `/a/` and `/u/` aren't real subdirectories, then you don't need the conditions. For the additional parameter, you need a 3rd rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]+)$ /anime.php?watch=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /anime.php?watch=$1&ep=$2 [L]
```